# Discord Role Reaction bot : cannot read property 'MessageEmbed'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

**created A reaction role bot with discord.js  ** in this we have to respond by emoji given there and the bot will give you the role.
but when I do so it gives me the following error:

C:\Users\RAJAS\Desktop\getrole\commands\role.js:14
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'MessageEmbed' of undefined
at Object.execute (C:\Users\RAJAS\Desktop\getrole\commands\role.js:14:33)
at Client. (C:\Users\RAJAS\Desktop\getrole\main.js:46:37)

Here Is my Code :

```
module.exports = {
name: 'role',
description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
    const channel = '786624094614585435';
    const teamMIKE = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "MIKE");
    const teamOSCAR = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "OSCAR");

    const teamMIKEEmoji = '';
    const teamOSCAREmoji = '';

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#e42643')
        .setTitle('Choose a team to play on!')
        .setDescription('Choosing a team will allow you to interact with your teammates!\n\n')
        .addFields(
            + `${teamMIKEEmoji} for MIKE team\n`
            + `${teamOSCAREmoji} for OSCAR team`);

    let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
    messageEmbed.react(teamMIKEEmoji);
    messageEmbed.react(teamOSCAREmoji);

    client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
        if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
        if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
        if (user.bot) return;
        if (!reaction.message.guild) return;

        if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
            if (reaction.emoji.name === teamMIKEEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(teamMIKE);
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === teamOSCAREmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(teamOSCAR);
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }

    });

    client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {

        if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
        if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
        if (user.bot) return;
        if (!reaction.message.guild) return;


        if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
            if (reaction.emoji.name === teamMIKEEmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(teamMIKE);
            }
            if (reaction.emoji.name === teamOSCAREmoji) {
                await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(teamOSCAR);
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a `const Discord = require('discord.js');` at the top of your file.

Comment: Try putting it above the let embed =

Comment: @RAJAS BHINGARDE if this solved your Question please mark this Answer as the Accepted Answer with the Green Tick, this will mark this Question as resovled.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead from this:

```js
let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
```

to This:

```js
let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).